# Erro ordenar lista?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
ViewBag.ListaEspecialidades = Especialidade.ListarEspecialidades().Sort();
```

Da um erro

> "cannot implicitly convert type void to dynamic".

Comment: deu certo a resposta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o OrderBy(x => x.NomeDoCampo) ou OrderByDescending(x => x.NomeDoCampo).

**Exemplo:**

```
ViewBag.ListaEspecialidades = Especialidade.ListarEspecialidades().OrderBy(x => x.NomeDoCampo);
```

Answer (score 7):

Acredito que isso resolva:

```
Especialidade.ListarEspecialidades().Sort();
ViewBag.ListaEspecialidades = Especialidade.ListarEspecialidades();
```

O `Sort()` é um metodo `void` não tem retorno, por isso do `erro`, tem a funcionalidade de ordenar a lista atual.